# how to properly create dark theme for android app?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create a dark theme and have full control over which elements get which color. i defined a ``color(night)`in`value(night)`resource and added some colors and changed`themes(night)`colors. but when i use`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`its seems that none of those defined colors are being used. the`Action Bar``` is the same color as the background for some reason and none of the colors I defined in color resources are being used. I tried to define my own theme but everything got kind of messy.

what is the proper way to create a dark theme and define custom colors in it?

Answer (score 0):

To use dark mode on your app You've got to create styles in night values.
Your app's night theme style must extend **Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
....
```